# I'm having a problem when entering an expression IN SSIS Conditional split task. All the Columns are Varchar

Tags: sql-server, ssis, expression, etl, conditional-split

*Conditional Split Expression:*

```
REPLACENULL(AddressLine1Txt,"") != REPLACENULL(OldAddressLine1Txt_1,"") ||
REPLACENULL(AddressLine2Txt,"") != REPLACENULL(OldAddressLine2Txt_1,"") || 
REPLACENULL(HouseTypeDesc,"") != REPLACENULL(OldHouseTypeDesc_1,"") || 
REPLACENULL(LatitudeNum,"") != REPLACENULL(OldLatitudeNum_1,"") || 
REPLACENULL(LongitudeNum,"") != REPLACENULL(OldLongitudeNum_1,"") || 
REPLACENULL(MeterReadInstructionCd,"") != REPLACENULL(OldMeterReadInstructionCd_1,"") || 
REPLACENULL(MeterReadInstructionDesc,"") != REPLACENULL(OldMeterReadInstructionDesc_1,"") || 
REPLACENULL(MeterReadWarningCd,"") != REPLACENULL(OldMeterReadWarningCd_1,"") || 
REPLACENULL(MeterReadWarningDesc,"") != REPLACENULL(OldMeterReadWarningDesc_1,"") ||  
REPLACENULL(PremiseTypeDesc,"") != REPLACENULL(OldPremiseTypeDesc_1,"")
```

Comment: What is the problem?  You need some details

Comment: What is your error? What is your result?